# My Favicon won't Appear

Tags: html, favicon

Ok so recently I started building a website and I realized that I needed a favicon so I made one put it in a favicon generator got it out and I have tried linking to it, and just plain inserting the image in the head but I can't seem to get it to work. It is a 16x16 photo saved as favicon.ico It still won't show up? it's in the same folder as my html along with the rest of the website do I need to put "http://favicon.com" instead I have tried using the debugger and network inspector but it won't acknowledge that's it there could it be the photo itself because I made it in illustrator then made it a jpg in photoshop?

Here's my code:

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

<meta name="keywords" content="resume, mason britt, portfolio">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
```

[image: Click here for the link to my snippet of the debugger]

Comment: open the inspector in your browser and on the network tab check if the favicon gets loaded correctly does it give you a 404 error? And if not try to press ctrl+f5 in your browser to reload the page without any saved cache.

Comment: According to this your *favicon* is in the same folder as the `html`

Comment: I would post the relevant HTML code (probably just the header of the file) in the question.

Comment: Here's a good rule of thumb when linking resources in CSS: Almost never will you need to use a relative path.  Relative paths are any typical path that does not begin with a `/` or protocol (`http://`, `https://`, or `//`).  If your linked resource doesn't begin with one of those four parts, you're probably not linking it correctly.